# Closed form expression of a summation

Tags: algorithms, summation, closed-form

My prof started out with the following summation:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
Which is all fine and dandy, however the summation we want to find the closed form of is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}(3i+1) = ?
\end{equation}
Which I did the following to:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}(3i+1) = 3\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + 1
\end{equation}

However her answer was:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}(3i+1) = 3\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1)
\end{equation}

Is there some summation rule I am missing? How did that $(k+1)$ get added towards the end?

Comment: Is the second equation $\sum (3i+1)$ or $\left(\sum 3i\right)+1$?

Comment: You forgot to sum $1$  (in your $3i+1$) for $i$ from $0$ to $k$, which yields you the term $(k+1)$.

Comment: Sorry its ∑(3i+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the second line should have brackets around the $(3i+1)$. Then:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k(3i+1)=\sum_{i=0}^k3i+\sum_{i=0}^k1$$

As summation is linear, we can apply your prof's formula to the first term.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}1 = k+1
\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the sum :
$\sum_0^k 1 =k+1$ and not $1$